# Symfony 1.4 Jobeet Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, symfony-1.4

i am learn symfony 1.4 by jobeet tutorial, and now I learn about **Ajax** (http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/18?orm=Doctrine)

everything *is working very well* but **I do not know how it's work**,

in tutorial it said to create **search.js**  and code below :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('.search input[type="submit"]').hide();

  $('#search_keywords').keyup(function(key)
  {
    if (this.value.length >= 3 || this.value == '')
    {
      $('#loader').show();
      $('#jobs').load(
        $(this).parents('form').attr('action'),
        { query: this.value + '*' },
        function() { $('#loader').hide(); }
      );
    }
  });
});
```

my question is where is AJAX code ? I cannot find Jquery code/Js code that works for ajax process ?

Comment: are you aware that symfony 1.4 has reached its end of life and current version of Symfony is 2.6? I ask, because maybe you should not learn version 1.4 but new one (Symfony 1.x and Symfony 2.x are completely different)

Comment: yes I aware about that, It because my next project is still using Symfony 1.4 as main framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check jquery's `load` method [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/). This is where ajax call is performed

Comment: I missed that, I though ajax only use get(), post(), ajax()